# remove row from pivot table in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have tables `(projects, roles, scopes, shifts, users)` and a table `(project_role_scope_shift_user)` as pivot.

I want to delete specific row like:

```
[project_id = 1 , scope_id = 2 , ... ]
```

However, detach method doesn't work correctly.

```
$user->roles()->detach(role)      !not working   => removes all rows of that role

$user->roles()->detach(role, ['project_id' => $projectId, 'scope_id' => $scopeId, 'shift_id' => $shiftId]);  => this does not work too, removes all rows of that role
```

Comment: I don't realy understand how the `roles` relation works here. Could you post both your `User` and `Role` model? Also, what is the value of the `$role` variable you pass to the `detach()` function?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$user->roles()->wherePivot(['project_id' => $projectId, 'scope_id' => $scopeId, 'shift_id' => $shiftId])->detach();
```

Comment: $user->roles()
                                    ->wherePivot('project_id', $projectId)
                                    ->wherePivot('scope_id', $scopeId)
                                    ->wherePivot('shift_id', $shiftId)
                                    ->detach(Role::query()->where('id', $roleId)->first());